# Trace path of HTTP GET request through Express middleware in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to debug my application and in doing so I realized I don't fully understand how an HTTP GET request finds its way down to the route.  In other words, when we configure middleware like this:

```
app.configure(function(){
  // options
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  // middleware
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));

  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

every HTTP request of any kind is fed in stages through the middleware, right?

The problem I'm having is that somewhere in my middleware, the `users` collection in my database is being queried and `req.user` is being populated with the incorrect `user` document, and I'm having trouble figuring out where that could possibly be happening.  I know my middleware is the culprit but my debugging abilities have begun to fail me at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is my passport setup:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function( username, password, done ) {  
  models.User.authenticate( username, password, function( err, user) {
    // reports CORRECT user
    console.log('\nmodels.User.authenticate callback');
    console.log('--username is ' + user.username);
    console.log(util.inspect(user));

    // return done( err, user );
    return done( err, user);
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function( user, done ) {
  // reports CORRECT user
  console.log('\npassport.serializeUser');
  console.log('--username is ' + user.username);
  console.log('--user._id is ' + user._id);
  console.log(util.inspect(user));
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  // reports CORRECT user id
  console.log('\npassport.deserializeUser()');
  console.log('user._id is ' + id);
  models.User.findOne( id, function (err, user) {

    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

It appears that serializeUser and deserializeUser work as expected.  They both report proper credentials when logged.

Comment: Passport setup looks okay to me. Is the incorrect user always the same, or just random? Also, you don't seem to be using a session store, which means sessions are reset every time your app restarts, although I don't think that could cause your problem. Btw, to trace middleware workflow, you can use `env DEBUG=connect:dispatcher node yourapp.js` if you're using an Unix-ish OS.

Comment: The incorrect user is always the first user in the database.  In other words, if we started with a blank database and signed up a few users, the only user that gets logged in is the first user to sign up, no matter what.

Comment: I used WireShark to see when the query is happening that is returning the incorrect user, and it's after the redirect to get /user happens, after the user's credentials are verified by Passport.  I'm guessing it's somewhere in Passport's session strategy that some database call is made, but I'm struggling to make sense of that... it's database agnostic, right?  So how could it or any other middleware query my database?

Comment: `deserializeUser` makes that database call: it's called for every request and takes the value stored in the session (`_id`) to convert it to a `user` object. This assumes that `_id` is always unique to one user, but since you're using MongoDB it most likely is.

Comment: Nailed it.  I'd been chasing that bug down for an embarrassing amount of time.  THANK YOU SO MUCH.